# PHP: Area and Circumference solutions

Tags: php, area, pow

I need some guidance as I have code below i need to solve and I'm not sure if I've done them correctly or not because I feel they are right and I am getting an output but I'm not sure if its the right output.

Basically I need to find the circumference and area, when the given radius is 20.0. I have the need equation at the top of each code snippet. I just want to know if I am right or along the right tracks as I'am new to PHP.

```
// = 2//

$r = 20.0;
$Area = pi() * (pow($r,2)); //PI = 3.1415926535898
echo $Area, '<br/>';
```

---

```
// = 2//

$Circumference = 2 * pi() * $r;
echo $Circumference, '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is working properly.

**Area**

```
// = 2//
$r = 20.0;
$Area = pi() * (pow($r,2)); //PI = 3.1415926535898
echo $Area, '<br/>';
```

**Your output: 1256.6370614359**

**Google output:**

[image: Google screenshot]

---

**Circumference**

```
// = 2//
$Circumference = 2 * pi() * $r;
echo $Circumference, '<br/>';
```

**Your output: 125.66370614359**

**Google output:**

[image: Google screenshot]

---

You could make it a little bit better by adding functions:

```
function calculateCircleArea($r) {
    return pi() * (pow($r,2));
}

function calculateCircleCircumference($r) {
    return 2 * pi() * $r;
}

echo calculateCircleArea(20.0).'<br/>';
echo calculateCircleCircumference(20.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine.
Also, put 4 spaces for each code so that they can be showed to others as code snippet. Otherwise, your code will not likely to be easy-readable.

Comment: i appreciate it bro